# PHP MySQL SELECT Query only returning resources

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

I'm currently working on building a download platform in which a user receives a random code and uses it to access an mp3 for download for up to three downloads. I generated a list of random codes using Python and imported them into a SQL table with an empty column for an associated email addresses and a default 0 for the use count. I wrote the following PHP script in order to associate an email with a certain code and add to the count so a download can be accessed up to three times.

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$email = stripslashes($email);
$uniqueCode = $_POST["uniqueCode"];
$uniqueCode = stripslashes($uniqueCode);

// check that all fields are filled
if($uniqueCode=="" || $email=="")
    apologize("Please fill out all fields.");

// check to make sure that the e-mail is valid
if (verifyEmail($email) == FALSE)
    apologize("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");

// check if uniqueCode input is alphanumeric 
if (verifyCode($uniqueCode) == FALSE)
    apologize("Download codes are alphanumeric.");

// check to see if unique code is correct 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wd009 where uniqueCode='$uniqueCode'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 

if($sql==FALSE)
{
    apologize("Your download code is invalid. Please try again");
}
// only allow users with less than 3 downloads to proceed
else if ($result['count'] <= 3) {
        if ($result['email'] == ""){
            mysql_query("UPDATE wd009 SET email='$email', count=1 WHERE uniqueCode='$uniqueCode'");
            apologize("added email"); 
            }
        else if ($result['email'] != $email)
            apologize("different email from record!!"); 
        else if ($result['email'] == $email){
            mysql_query("UPDATE wd009 SET count=count+1 WHERE uniqueCode='$uniqueCode'");
            apologize("updated the count!"); 

}
else 
    apologize("Your download code is used up!");
```

Obviously I use some functions in the above that aren't included in the code but I've checked all of them and none of them should interfere with the MySQL query. It may be of note that apologize() exits immediately after apologizing. When I input a correct code into the form, it works correctly and updates the SQL database. However, as long as the download code input is alphanumeric, the form will accept it even though the string definitely does not match any in the table. Namely, mysql_query returns a resource no matter the input. I've checked the database connection but since the table is correctly updated when the download code is correct, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I've tried debugging this every way I could think of and am genuinely befuddled. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd say if you use PDO you will feel more familiar. It does not uses these resources thingies any longer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the manual, [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) always returns a resource for a valid query so you need to change your logic and count the number of rows it returns, not the result of `mysql_query`.

Apart from that, `mysql_query`, is deprecated and you should use mysqli or PDO.

You can count the number of rows with the - equally deprecated  - `mysql_num_rows` function. 0 rows would be no valid code in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
if($sql==FALSE)
```

should probably be something like

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
```

Edit: I agree, mysqli or PDO is preferred now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably is this line:

```
if($sql==FALSE)
{
    apologize("Your download code is invalid. Please try again");
}
```

Since the sql is a string it is accepting is as true and passing it as valid.  One thing you also might like to do to avoid sql injection is use parameters instead of directly injecting user input.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wd009 where uniqueCode='$uniqueCode'");
```

Instead, do something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM wd009 where uniqueCode=?");
$stmt->bind_param($uniqueCode);
$stmt->execute();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   .....
```

You'll also want to do it this way for the update statement too.

If you have a lot of data in that table you may want to restrict the columns returned in the SQL statement so it lessens the load on the database.